# Loading java classes into ORACLE database error : ()Ljava/util/List;) catch_type not a subclass of Throwable

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, ibm-mq

I was trying to load java classes into database using the loadjava tool, but I am getting a warning which is causing an error when calling the java methode from PLSQL procedure.

ERROR :

> ORA-29552: verification warning: java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
>   com/mq/RIMSmqToolsIn,   method: mqRead signature: ()Ljava/util/List;)
>   catch_type not a subclass of Throwable

I think this is a dependencie issue for some missing java class which need to be resolved using loadjava tool but I could not figure what jar need to be used and how is the correct cmd using laodjava ?

NB: I tried to use a jar file that contains java.util.List.class but I still get the warning when loading

Java Version:

```
java -version java version "1.6.0_39" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
```

To load I first compile using shell script:

```
javac -source 1.4 \ -target 1.4 \ -classpath ./com.ibm.mq.jar:./connector.jar:$CLASSPATH \ $SOURCES
```

Then I load :

```
loadjava -force -definer -resolve -synonym -grant rims_user_role -user $DB_CONNECT_STRING -verbose $CLASSES
```

Comment: What is the JRE version?

Comment: 11.5.1 DEV115 dev115> java -version
java version "1.6.0_39"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: To load I first compile using shell script: 
javac -source 1.4                                                                      \
      -target 1.4                                                                           \
      -classpath ./com.ibm.mq.jar:./connector.jar:$CLASSPATH \
      $SOURCES

Then I load :loadjava -force -definer -resolve -synonym -grant rims_user_role -user $DB_CONNECT_STRING -verbose $CLASSES

Comment: Could this be an issue with you defining 1.4 but using JRE 1.6?

Comment: I have to use 1.4 otherwise I will get another error :  
ORA-29552: verification warning: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/gltrade/rims/mq/RIMSmqIn (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)

Comment: But you aren't loading it into a target of 1.4... you're loading into a target of 1.6.

Comment: How can I execute loadjava with JRE 1.4 instead of 1.6 when having both installed into my system ?
OR Can I use my existing JRE 1.6 to solve this issue ?

Comment: What was the class file compiled with?

Comment: I compile the file using  JRE 1.6 (the only one available now on my system)
javac -source 1.4 \ -target 1.4 \ -classpath ./com.ibm.mq.jar:./connector.jar:$CLASSPATH \ $SOURCES

Comment: It was compiled with other .jar =  connector.jar  and com.ibm.mq.jar , and also other file which are user defined

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the dependency jar files loaded in separate load java command.
Load all the jar files in a single loadjava command as below:
loadjava -u sys/welcome1 -r -v -f -s -grant public -genmissing xyz.jar xyz1.jar

Before loading the jar files drop them from the database.

https://community.oracle.com/message/13161867#13161867